# WPF telerik GridView aggregate is not updating until focus out of a grid view field

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid

telerik:GridView, using aggregate function to show sum in footer, the property is being updated from somewhere else and GridView is not calling PropertyChanged until focus out from GridView Column.
How we can refresh aggregate as soon as Item-source Property is changed.

I want to get aggregate updated as soon as ItemSource Property is updated.

On GridView property change I am using

```
private void GV_PropertyChanged(object s, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
GV.CalculateAggregate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/troubleshooting/aggregates-not-updated), it seems like you should raise the `CollectionChanged` event for the source collection:

> In order to get the aggregate results refreshed, you have to notify
> the GridView that the bound collection has been changed. A
> CollectionChanged notification of the bound collection should be
> raised.
>
> There are four possible solutions:
>
> You can update the value as illustrated in this help article on how to
> edit an item outside RadGridView.
>
> Ensure that a CollectionChanged event is raised from the bound source
> collection.
>
> Invoke RadGridView.CalculateAggregates() method.
>
> Invoke RadGridView.Rebind() method. It will raise CollectionChanged
> notification with action Reset. Please note that the entire view will
> be recreated.